# My CPT Category only showing 10 items when i have 15?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

My CPT Category is only showing 10 items when there should be 15. The category has a count of 15 but the page is only showing 10.

[Picture of CPT category counting 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3vYT.png)

However if you check my page out below you can see that only 10 are listed.

https://athleteperks.co.uk/perk_categories/free-membership/

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you talk about archive page of blog or listing?
Should be a classic error, go to Settings -> Reading and in Blog Pages field change in 20 or more